# prevent p-table sorting when all the rows has same value in a column and don't change sorting icon as there is no change in the table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, p-table

I am using primeng 14 version in an Angular 14 project. The issue scenario is, in a table, one specific column has same value in all rows. When I tried to click sort icon on the column, there is no sorting is happening. Data in all columns remains same but the sorting icon is changing. The expectation is since there is no sorting performed, the icons should not change.

I am looking for some input to handle this. Appreciate your input.

Thanks.

Comment: Uhh, don't mark the column as `pSortableColumn` if all values in that column are the same?

Comment: We can do that. But that may permanently remove the sorting from the column. For my case, need to show the sorting icons but there should be no change as there is no sorting performing